# Passing HTTP into Angular 2 service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular2-services, ngrx

I'm currently getting an error that says "can't read property 'get' of null" which is because I'm passing in null as my first argument to the FirmService constructor in my beforeEach in my spec file...what is the best way to mock or pass in http to my service here?

```
@Injectable
export class FirmService {
 public stateObservable: Observable<FirmState>;

 constructor(private: $http: AuthHttp, private store: Store<FirmState>) {
    this.stateObservable = this.store.select('firmReducer');

  }

  public getFirms(value?: string) {
     return this.$http.get('/api/firm').map((response: Response) => {
           this.store.dispatch({
               type: firmActions.GET_FIRMS,
               payload: response.json()
            });
            return;
     }
  }
}
```

Here is my unit test for the above service:

```
import {Store} from '@ngrx/store';
import {FirmService} from './firm.service'
import {firmActions} from './firm.reducer'
import {FirmState} from './firm.state'
import {HttpModule, Http, Response, ResponseOptions, XHRBackend} from 'angular/http';
import {MockBackend, MockConnection} from '@angular/http/testing';

class MockStore extends Store<FirmState> {
    constructor() {
        super(null, null, null)
    }

    public dispatch () {
         return undefined;
     }
}

describe('firm actions', () => {
     it('getFirms should dispatch the GET_FIRMS action', () => {
          let connection: MockConnection;
          const expectedAction = {
             type: firmActions.GET_FIRMS
             payload: undefined
          }

 const mockBackendResponse = (connection: MockConnection, response: string) => {
  connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({ body: response })));

      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
           imports: [HttpModule],
           providers: [
               {provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend}
           ]
       });

    spyOn(mockStore, 'dispatch');
    firmService.getFirms().subscribe(result => {
       expect(mockStore.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalled();
       expect(mockStore.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedAction);
    };
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: could it be this private: $http, AutHttp you have a comma

Comment: @Nello, sorry I made the correction in my post. I'm basically trying to understand the best way to satisfy the http call in my getFirms function from my spec file

Answer (score 1):

you can try something using MockBackend and MockConnection from angular's http/testing library:

```
import { ResponseOptions, Response, XHRBackend, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';

const mockBackendResponse = (connection: MockConnection, response: string) => {
  connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({ body: response })));
};

// test module configuration for each test
const testModuleConfig = () => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      //.. your required modules for this test,
      HttpModule, RouterTestingModule
    ],
    providers: [
      // required services,
      { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend }
    ]
  });
};
```

then before each test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
      injector = getTestBed();
      backend = <any>injector.get(XHRBackend);
      store = injector.get(Store);
      // sets the connection when someone tries to access the backend with an xhr request
      backend.connections.subscribe((c: MockConnection) => connection = c);

      // construct after setting up connections above
        firmService = injector.get(FirmService);
    });
```

sample test using an Array of Items as result:

```
t.it('should search', () => {

let list: Array<Item> = []; // ... your sample mock entity with fields

      observer.subscribe(result => {
        expect(result).toEqual(new SearchedAction(list));
      });

      // mock response after the xhr request (which happens in constructor), otherwise it will be undefined
      let expectedJSON:string = JSON.stringify(list);
      mockBackendResponse(connection, expectedJSON);
}
```